# ORA-00904: invalid identifier with left outer join

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter, join

I'm having trouble with my queries. It says :

```
ORA-00904: "KT"."urutan"."ED"."id_evaluasi": invalid identifier
```

Im trying to figure it out but i cant seem to find the problem.

```
        $query = $this->db->query('
        SELECT 
            ED."id_kategori",
            KT."kategori",
            ED."id_evaluasi",
            KT."urutan",
            ED."id_perspektif"
        FROM "evaluasidetails" ED
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "kategoris" KT ON KT."id_kategori" = ED."id_kategori"
        WHERE ED."id_evaluasidetail" = '.$id_evaluasi.'
        GROUP BY ED."id_perspektif",ED."id_kategori", KT."kategori", KT."urutan". ED."id_evaluasi"
        ORDER BY KT."urutan" ASC
        ');
```

Please help me. Im really stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a missing `comma` on your `group by`

```
 $query = $this->db->query('
        SELECT 
            ED."id_kategori",
            KT."kategori",
            ED."id_evaluasi",
            KT."urutan",
            ED."id_perspektif"
        FROM "evaluasidetails" ED
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "kategoris" KT ON KT."id_kategori" = ED."id_kategori"
        WHERE ED."id_evaluasidetail" = '.$id_evaluasi.'
        GROUP BY ED."id_perspektif", ED."id_kategori", KT."kategori", KT."urutan",  ED."id_evaluasi"
        ORDER BY KT."urutan" ASC
        ');
```